# gradle: Could not get unknown property 'runtimeClasspath' for task

Tags: gradle

I have the following simple build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task foo(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'gradletest2.Main'
    classpath = runtimeClasspath
}
```

which when executed causes the following error to be generated:

```
C:\Users\J\Documents\Development\eclipse-photon\gradletest2>gradle foo

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\J\Documents\Development\eclipse-photon\gradletest2\build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradletest2'.
> Could not get unknown property 'runtimeClasspath' for task ':foo' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

BTW Main is simply:

```
package gradletest2;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        System.out.println("gradletest2");
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error?  I am following an official gradle tutorial video on YT at https://youtu.be/OFUEb7pLLXw?t=2043, but unfortunately it is quite old, so I am wondering if this is now incorrect syntax. 
Thanks in advance.

I'm using gradle 4.10.2.

Comment: What is the version of gradle you're using? And why do you put your build script under src/main/java/? This directory is for Java source files.

Comment: Hi, I'm using 4.10.2. I put the gradle file in src/main/java because I'm stupid..ahem, yes, I just thought eclipse wouldn't allow me to create a file directly under the project node i.e. not in a source folder, but I've just done exactly that. Very silly. Thanks. Btw the error is still generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`runtimeClasspath` is a property of your main sourceSet. The correct syntax is

```
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That error has gone. I am though now getting `C:\Users\J\Documents\Development\eclipse-photon\gradletest2>gradle foo

> Task :foo FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class gradletest2.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gradletest2.Main`  Should I create a new question for this?

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed my answer. The previous one compiles,but doesn't do what you're after. Note that this is documented, with an example, in the JavaExec documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html